# MySQL Explain statement: All attributes are nulls

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have a table with the following structure (I try to make it formatted, it looks good in preview but fails after publish):
| id | col_a | col_b|
|:--:|:--:|:--:|
|1|0|0|

Here is the Create Table DDL (The only index is the primary key):

```
CREATE TABLE `meta` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'record\'s id',
`col_a` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'value 1',
`col_b` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'value 2',

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='meta';
```

Then we execute the EXPLAIN statement for the following query:
`explain select * from meta where id=2 and col_a = 1 and col_b=1;`

Here is the output:
[image: explanation]

May I ask why all attributes are NULL? I did do some research, but they are all related to the NULL key value, and none of them explains why the rest are NULL and their meanings.

Cheers

Comment: Because you do not have any joins, so there is no point in showing any of information related to tables joins optimizations

Answer (score 0):

As the extra section of the explain indicates, there is no record that matches your where clause, so there is little point in performing any analysis. Run the explain with a where clause that does return some values. Please note that running explain on small tables may also yield strange outputs as it may be cheaper for mysql to perform a full table scan rather than use indexes in this case.